# modal popup displaying first item details on all buttons of items

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am implementing dress shopping website. Home page displays all dress with description in grid with individual 'Add to cart' button. On clicking the button, modal popup shows up with item price and quantity. But each modal popup loads only first item description instead of their own description. Here is the code:

```
<button class="update fa fa-shopping-cart " id="mpopupLink1" onclick="openModal2()" title="Add to Cart" type="image"  style=" margin-top: 90px; margin-left:110px;   width: 35px; height: 35px; background: white; "  /></button>

// here is starting modal popup
<div id="mpopupBox1" class="mpopup1">
    <!-- mPopup content -->
    <div class="mpopup1-content">
        <div class="mpopup1-head">
            <span class="close8">×</span>
            <h2 style="font-family:Cooper Black;"><center>Add to Cart</center></h2>    
        </div>
        <div class="mpopup1-main" >
            <br/>
            <br/>         
            <p>
                <b>Product Code: <?php echo $row['id']; ?></b>
            </p> 
            <div style="margin: 30px 40px 40px 250px;">
                <p id="demo">
                    <font size="6" ><b>PKR</b></font>
                    <input name="price" type="number" id="price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" readonly> </font>
                    <br/>
                </p> 
            </div>
            <div style="margin: -75px 60px 40px 0px;" >
                <label><font size="4">Quantity</font></label>   
            </div>  
            <input  style="margin-left: 335px; margin-top: -40px; width: 135px;" type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="button button4 add-to-cart" value="Add to Cart">
        </div>
        <div class="mpopup1-foot">
            <!-- <p>created by CodexWorld</p> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

// here is javascript function
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mpopup1 = document.getElementById('mpopupBox1');

    // get the link that opens the mPopup
    var mpLink1 = document.getElementById("mpopupLink1");

    // get the close action element
    var close8 = document.getElementsByClassName("close8")[0];

    // open the mPopup once the link is clicked
    mpLink1.onclick = function() {
        mpopup1.style.display = "block";
    }

    var images1 = document.querySelectorAll('button[title="Add to Cart"]');
    for(var i=0, len = images1.length; i < len; i++){
        images1[i].addEventListener('click', openModal2);
    }

    function openModal2() {
        mpopup1.style.display = "block";          
    }

    // close the mPopup once close element is clicked
    close8.onclick = function() {
        mpopup1.style.display = "none";
    }

    // close the mPopup when user clicks outside of the box

</script>
```

Comment: AS per your code its obvious to show data of 1st item only. Instead of just show/hide the popup pass the id of the item, fetch data from database and load the modal popup. Or else make the modal popup id dynamic & show the relevant popup on 'Add to cart' button click.

Comment: @ AAT  how i can make id dynamic? can you please help?

Comment: Are you using the modal popup in foreach loop?

Comment: no i am not using foreach loop

Comment: Then just pass the id of each item in  onclick="openModal2($row['id'])". In openModal2() fetch data related to that particular item and dynamically bind that to modal popup

Comment: i just put it in onclick but still not working. can you please edit this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="update fa fa-shopping-cart " id="mpopupLink1" onclick="openModal2($row['id'])" title="Add to Cart" type="image"  style=" margin-top: 90px; margin-left:110px;   width: 35px; height: 35px; background: white; "  /></button>

// here is starting modal popup
<div id="mpopupBox1" class="mpopup1">
    <!-- mPopup content -->
    <div class="mpopup1-content">
        <div class="mpopup1-head">
            <span class="close8">×</span>
            <h2 style="font-family:Cooper Black;"><center>Add to Cart</center></h2>    
        </div>
        <div class="mpopup1-main" >
            <br/>
            <br/>         
            <p>
                <b>Product Code: </b><span id="row_id"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></span>
            </p> 
            <div style="margin: 30px 40px 40px 250px;">
                <p id="demo">
                    <font size="6" ><b>PKR</b></font>
                    <input name="price" type="number" id="price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" readonly> </font>
                    <br/>
                </p> 
            </div>
            <div style="margin: -75px 60px 40px 0px;" >
                <label><font size="4">Quantity</font></label>   
            </div>  
            <input  style="margin-left: 335px; margin-top: -40px; width: 135px;" type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="button button4 add-to-cart" value="Add to Cart">
        </div>
        <div class="mpopup1-foot">
            <!-- <p>created by CodexWorld</p> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

// here is javascript function
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mpopup1 = document.getElementById('mpopupBox1');

    // get the link that opens the mPopup
    var mpLink1 = document.getElementById("mpopupLink1");

    // get the close action element
    var close8 = document.getElementsByClassName("close8")[0];

    // open the mPopup once the link is clicked
    mpLink1.onclick = function() {
        mpopup1.style.display = "block";
    }

    var images1 = document.querySelectorAll('button[title="Add to Cart"]');
    for(var i=0, len = images1.length; i < len; i++){
        images1[i].addEventListener('click', openModal2);
    }

    function openModal2(id) {
      //write the code to fetch data from Database using that id. I am not sure about your database details. So please do it yourself.
        document.getElementById('row_id').value = name(javascript variable);// like this push value to every element you want to show
        mpopup1.style.display = "block";          
    }

    // close the mPopup once close element is clicked
    close8.onclick = function() {
        mpopup1.style.display = "none";
    }

    // close the mPopup when user clicks outside of the box

</script>
```

Comment: what is row_id in openmodal2 function?

Comment: Id of the item which you want to add to cart

Comment: its not working still. i can share my database details with if you can complete openmodal2 function @ AAT

Comment: Update you code including for loop for display item . I will give it a try